# Why do dogs start barking/ howling at the time of Fajr Azan?

Tags: dogs

Okay, I noticed it often now a days.. whenever Imam starts azan for faraz prayer some dogs start barking together.. This is happening so often but not exactly daily. But they start barking exactly when imam starts the azan..

Is there any interpretation behind this? Does anybody else got into similar experience?

**Update:** I just noticed it happens every day. And they actually do not bark but just make a sound (that sounds like crying/ howling)..

Comment: Another best question I've found in this site. Although at first I thought this could be a silly question.

Comment: I found the fact interesting and it made me so curious ..so I started marking the dates when it happens from yesterday..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salam,

There is a clear hadith about dogs barking:

> The Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his
>   mention ) said: ‘‘If you hear the barking of a dog or the braying of a
>   donkey by night, then seek refuge in Allaah from the devil because
>   they see what you do not see.’’ [Ahmad and Abu Daawood].

Also, according to some other islamic source, when devil hears adhan,he runs away from there. So probably, when azan is pronunced,then devils run away and Dogs see them running and bark like this.

I hope that answers the question

Comment: @WailingNightingale you mean this hadith : http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/90

Comment: Crowing of a rooster is also not some coincidence. Here is another related hadith.:
 AbuHurayra(RA) narrated that the prophet (SAW) said: "When u hear the crowing of a cockerel(rooster), ask for Allah's Blessings for (their crowing indicates that) they have seen an angel. When u hear the braying of donkeys, seek refuge with Allah from Shaytaan for (their braying indicates that) they have seen a devil."
[Bukhari (6/350) and Muslim (17/47)]
And roosters' crowing is evident at particular times, like Fajr and Asr, because these are the shifting hours for the day and night angels. [Maalik, Nasai]

Comment: @hamza Islam bro, walaikumassala.. exactly.. I guessed the same that you said on the last line.. but needed to be confirm.. now feeling a bit afraid.

But another thing, before the faraz azan.. Allah come closer from the up, while its time to tahajjud prayer.. So, is it a safer time than the day time? does satan stays away on that time and when the fazar azan starts then the devil runway means he starts spreading or leaving?

Comment: @WailingNightingale..good information, I got a question after seeing this. We brought up some rooster, and they used to crowing almost all the day long.. few times in a hour atleast. So what does this mean? We then started getting complain from the neighbours, so had to give them away to a seller. :'(

Comment: @NadiaAli: Actually there is nothing to fear about. If you read Zikr of Allah after fajr prayer,then no devil can harm you at all, as hundreds of thousands of angel protect you from everywhere. Also, satan is a jinn. and jinn always are afraid of the one,whose iman is strong. Never be afraid of them,they can never harm you, unless Allah wills. so make them fear you,be brave. And it is better not to go out , specially women and children, till fahr time, from maghrib time,,because as soon as maghrib starts, jinn sha shayateen spread everywhere.

Comment: "And it is better not to go out , specially women and children, till fahr time, from maghrib time,,because as soon as maghrib starts, jinn sha shayateen spread everywhere." very important thing pointed out. Though its a bit difficult for working women and also for some to maintain.. thanks .. Jazakallah Khair

Comment: @NadiaAli: Nothing is difficult, if we are firm in following this life according to Quran and hadith. its for our own benefit. if we dont,then we will be among lsoers in hereasfter. Strictly follow Quran and Sunnah, no matter what you have,no mater what others say or think.

Comment: @WailingNightingale There's been scientific studies about the crowing of roosters; they work off their circadian cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Howling is a way of communication between canidae (exempla: give their position). Dogs have no idea what's music, adhan or an ambulance' siren, for them it's another canidae howling so they will try to communicate with it -through howling-.

There are many sources on internet, just google it, here's [one](http://www.petinsurance.com/healthzone/pet-articles/pet-behavior/Why-Do-Dogs-Howl-at-Sirens.aspx).

Comment: Scientifically, your answer is exact. It has been proved by studies. That you put adhan or anything else, they bark.

Answer (score 1):

> حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ خَالِدٍ، قَالَ‏:‏ حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ
>   إِسْحَاقَ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، عَنْ عَطَاءِ بْنِ
>   يَسَارٍ، عَنْ جَابِرِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللهِ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم قَالَ‏:‏ إِذَا سَمِعْتُمْ نُبَاحَ الْكِلاَبِ أَوْ نُهَاقَ
>   الْحَمِيرِ مِنَ اللَّيْلِ، فَتَعَوَّذُوا بِاللَّهِ، فَإِنَّهُمْ
>   يَرَوْنَ مَالاَ تَرَوْنَ، وَأَجِيفُوا الأَبْوَابَ، وَاذْكُرُوا اسْمَ
>   اللهِ عَلَيْهَا، فَإِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ لاَ يَفْتَحُ بَابًا أُجِيفَ
>   وَذُكِرَ اسْمُ اللهِ عَلَيْهِ، وَغَطُّوا الْجِرَارَ، وَأَوْكِئُوا
>   الْقِرَبَ وَأَكْفِئُوا الآنِيَةَ‏.‏
>
> Jabir ibn 'Abdullah reported that the Messenger of Allah(may Allah
>   bless him and grant him peace) said,
>
> "When you hear a dog barking or a
>   donkey braying in the night, seek refuge with Allah. They see what you
>   do not see. Shut the doors and mention the Name of Allah over them.
>   Shaytan will not open a door which has been shut and had the name of
>   Allah mentioned over it. Then cover the pots, tie the water-skins and
>   cover the vessels."

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum!
Dog is one of the creature Allah has brought into this duniyah and dog is a dog, its job is to bark. How else it will express? And any kind of sound or music affects them. As there are sounds created in the form of apps that can calm them down while they are hawling or barking. Similarly, In my neighborhood there is a dog which is left alone in the apartment when the owner is on his work. Since the owner leaves home, this dog keeps on hawling till she comes back home. I start playing the recitation of Qur'an and its quite always. The day I dont play recitation, it's terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I actually noticed, heard, clearly, for a few minutes at the time of 3:20 - 3:30am, south african time, the dogs across the town neighbourhood barking. Then of a sudden cocks started crowing and the barking subsided, in stages until it was very quiet. Then i heard the chirping of birds in the trees. I was on the verge of making wudhu for nafl salaah, before fajr. My ustahd and Imaam, told me two days ago that ay the third quarter of the night Allah descends lower than the 6th heaven, to hear those of His lovers worshipping Him, making duah and taubah. And accepts their prayers and supplications. So it makes sense that the devils run and the dogs bark to see them run while the cockerels crow to see the angels in their multitudes, at this very very powerful time. Allahu Akbar!

Comment: Try adding references